# Storing multiple derived class types in a single list

Tags: c++, list

I want to store multiple class types derived from the same base class in a single stl list.

If I use

```
list<BaseClass> L;
```

then my code compiles fine when I add any derived classes. However, it looks like my derived classes are automatically being casted down to the base type before being stored. Obviously I want to store the unique members of the derived types as well. How can I do this?

Comment: I guess you mean multiple objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use

```
list<BaseClass *> L;
```

But with this, you will have problems with exception safety (Where do you destroy the object when the list goes out of scope? What if some exception is thrown before?). So maybe this:

```
#include <list>
#include <tr1/memory>

std::list<std::tr1::shared_ptr<BaseClass> > L;
```

would be better. TR1 basic info can be found e.g. on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++_Technical_Report_1), its [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_tr1.html)
under the boost docs.

Comment: @KirilKirov It would only be a +1 if he had mentioned that these smart pointers are also in C++11 and that you could also use a `unique_ptr` if you don't need the overhead of a `shared_ptr`. I know this may not all belong into the answer, but in fact he was the one to start with smart pointers.

Comment: Christian Rau: I am aware of the `shared_ptr` overhead. But now it is the only solution without additional libraries (Boost) or a different standard (C++11).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the container as `list< Baseclass* >`

<strike>or `list< Baseclass& >` (the second one is a little dangerous).</strike> ( "deleted" thanks to @Cat Plus Plus's comment)

By using `list< Baseclass >`, you meet the [slicing issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c).

Comment: You can't use reference, because references are not assignable.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do what you want, you have to work with pointers. A possible solution is `std::list<BaseClass*>` but now you have to deal with copying, cloning, deleting. A better alternative is to use [Boost.Pointer Containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html), that do that automatically for you.