# Multiple class types in a single list

Tags: c++, list

Is it possible to store multiple different class types in a single `std::list` object?

I want to make multi-layered list that can store `int` and `std::list` as an element, and now am trying to use `std::list` for this purpose. I need to retrieve data from all the list from both top-level and subsequent layers too.

[This question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106676/storing-multiple-derived-class-types-in-a-single-list) is similar except that I want to use pre-defined class.

The following returns error at 4th line:

```
std::list<int> l;
std::list<int> subL;
l.push_back(1);
l.push_back(subL);
```

This returns error at 1st (and 3th according to the 1st line):

```
std::list l;
std::list<int> subL;
l.push_back(1);
l.push_back(subL);
```

Comment: P:lease stop writing tags in titles.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. But why do you want to do that? How would you use it later on?

Comment: @Nawaz thanks for pointing out. I updated my question to clarify the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare `list <void*>` and store to it pointers to any of your objects. But another question will raise how you're going distinguish them to use? If you don't need to, it's OK.

Comment: +1 but yeah, as I updated my question, I need to get the stored data and tell from each other.

Comment: The most simple solution - make whrapper class something like `struct w {void * value; bool isInt; };` and make list of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can store both types in a single value if you use something like [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/variant.html).