# C++ Reading Txt File, Line by line, storing multiple types in two lists, if present

Tags: c++, string, list, visual-studio-2013, file-io

I've been learning about reading text files recently, and have successfully been able to read, and store data into lists - which then allows me to sort nicely (I'm trying to learn to use lists, rather than Vectors atm, so answer using that would be perfect).

My problem is, when there is a change in the `textfiles` data types, where the structure is slightly different - I'll provide an example:

### Test.txt

```
Joe Smith 15 

Eileen Jones 4

Joey 12

James Rush 2
```

So, basically, I'm trying to read a file, which has changing data types, of an unspecified length. I'd ideally like to keep the first and last name together in a single stringstring, and then separate the integer - however also provide scope for a single string to be present.

From my searches, I've found that I should take the entire line as a string, then use `stringstream` to split the information - only problem, is that if the data changes from having two strings, to only one before the integer, then it won't store.

From there I have to store strings in one list and ints in another, whilst keeping first/last name together if they are both there - or not, if it's just a single string.

Hopefully this makes sense. I've been searching for days, and just can't find a way to do it. I would really appreciate some help!

Also, my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    list <string> eachLine;

    list <string> personName;

    list <int> favouriteNumber;

    int intStore;
    string strStore;

    ifstream userFile("Test.txt");

    // check if file is open
    if (!userFile)
    {
        cout << "\n\nCannot open file!\n\n";
        cin.get();
        return 1;
    }


    while (!userFile.eof())
    {
        userFile >> stringStore;

        eachLine.push_back(tempStore);

    }

    // ?????? Split Strings from list (eachLine) - so to have either
    // <string>, <string>, <int> or <string>, <int>. Then store
    // strings in list1 (personName) and ints in 
    // list2 (favouriteNumber)


    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple class types in a single list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454195/multiple-class-types-in-a-single-list)

Comment: A couple of things that stand out: First don't do `while (!userFile.eof())`, see e.g. ["Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). Secondly the input operator `>>` reads *space delimited* "tokens". Thirdly, if the file contains text, you need some way to read that first before you read the number.

Comment: Thanks, Joachim. Will look over the eof trouble - I am still new to C++, so appreciate the insight. The lists store all the info as lines - so I should be able to split them from there, but I don't know how to?

Answer (score 1):

You want to store it in list  favoritenumber

or do you want to store it in a new text file like strings in one and integers in the other ?

if you want the second option

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
```

if (!userFile)
    {
        cout << "\n\nCannot open file!\n\n";
        cin.get();
        return 1;
    }

```
while (!userFile.eof())
{
    userFile >> tempStore;

    favouriteNumber.push_back(tempStore);

}
ifstream userFile("Test.txt");
list <int> favouriteNumber;

oftream userF;
userF.open("INTEGERS.txt");
userF << favouriteNumber;


    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: It's more the former - integers in a list of their own, and the strings in their own list. Thanks for your answer so far.

Comment: You can use `getline` to read one line from the file into a `std::string`. Then you can put the string into a `stringstream` and use `>>` to extract the parts. Perhaps `if (stream >> first_name >> last_name >> number)` you know it worked `else` add the string to another stringstream and try the alternative.

Comment: Hi Bo, what you've suggested is what I think I am after. I was trying something like that, however I then had the result print back out to the console (just to check), and nothing appeared - so I wasn't sure if my data had even been saved? Then also, if there are two strings present, could I make them a single string instead, so that individual name are just held in a single string (so first / last as a single string & also allow just first by itself in another string)? What might this look like in code?

Comment: I was thinking maybe too - is there a way to check how many space delimiters there are, and if there are more than 2, skip the first, and separate the strings from that?? This way my strings would save exactly as I need them? I just have no idea how to do this in c++. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

After reading one line from the file (using `getline`), you could try to parse that as 3 elements. If it doesn't work, try again with 2 elements.

Or, if names are not allowed to start with digits (like 3M...), you could `peek()` at the first character and decide if it looks like a number, or not.

Comment: The parsing as three and then as two sounds like a solid way - any ideas how that might look in code? I'm pretty novice with c++, but doing my best to learn! Thank you for your answer.